# Copying uploaded image to the server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to store an image to the database by getting its name property, copying the original file into the server, and insert the name property into the database. Here's my code:

```php
$image = $_FILES["image"];  
$img_name = $image["name"];  
$img_tmp = $image["tmp_name"];
$dir = "../upload/$img_tmp";

// transfer image to server public dir
move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, $dir);

// Insert into database
```

I have read a few of questions on adding images through PHP but i still don't get it. It does not copy the file into the server at all, however it stores the name in the database.

Comment: actually it was the name of the image that you will store in the database not the image itself. you can visit w3school for image uploading

Comment: @SherwinObciana w3schools is *extremely* damaging as a lot of the advice they give is wickedly out of date.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: If you're having trouble storing attachments consider looking at [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that can facilitate this for you and provide a lot more in the way of security and safety features. They come in a variety of forms, from very light-weight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very full-featured like 
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: @tadman I know that it can damage your system but i dont think it is right to advice the OP much advanced framework because he is only asking about the file uploading

Comment: @SherwinObciana "I know that it can damage your system" is the reason to start with a framework and work backwards. They're not "too advanced". They come in a variety of forms, from sophisticated to simplistic. The important thing is to use one and not bash around with core PHP by thinking it's easier, because it's not. It's only easier to get quick results that aren't anything close to secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for  [Uploading image](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) . I hope it helps you

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the code for uploading image. You just need to get the name of the file and stored it in your database